# Transfer game to another phone

Tags: pokemon-go

My daughter didn't have a phone that allowed the Pokemon go App so we downloaded it on to my S6. She now has a phone that allows the app. Could you please tell me how I transfer her game from my S6 to her Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime? She doesn't want to be forced to start over. I am technology challenged so I the information as simple as possible. Also is it possible to change the email to hers?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use her new phone to sign in with her Pokémon Trainer Club/Google account(ask whatever she was using before), then delete the app from your phone. Redownload it and sign in as your own trainer if you wish to play the game yourself.